# How to display the name of context in catalina.out?

Tags: java, logging, tomcat6

I have 3 webapp running in tomcat 6,catalina.out,i use system.out.println("") for log,i want to display the name of webapp near each log ?

Comment: Why don't you use some logging framework like log4j?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using system.out.println for logging is not that recommended. I suggest you'll look into some logging framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [slf4j](http://www.slf4j.org/)

Comment: hello spiderman, i know log4j but all webapp use system.out for logging, i just want to khnow if there are a way to have some config in tomcat to display the name of webapp ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the request using [`HttpServletRequest.getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getContextPath()) or directly from the servlet context using [`ServletContext.getContextPath()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContextPath()):

```
System.out.println(req.getContextPath() + " - " + "Your log message")
```

Obviously it would be better to use a logging framework.